# Check for first occurrence of string in C# using the string.contains function

Tags: c#, string

I have a custom log window using RichTextBox, where I highlight log messages from a third party console app (running in a `Process` with Standard Input/Error redirect).

The log messages appears like this:

```
[Info] Bla bla bla
[Status] Bla bla bla
[SQL] Bla bla bla
```

I want to highlight the text according to output type (`[Info]`, `[Status]`, `[SQL]` etc...), so I wrote these few lines of code to determine message colour:

```
// Workout message colour
Color messageColor = normalText;
if (outputMessage.Contains("[SQL]"))
    messageColor = sqlText;
else if (outputMessage.Contains("[Status]"))
    messageColor = statusText;
else if (outputMessage.Contains("[Warning]"))
    messageColor = warningText;
else if (outputMessage.Contains("[Notice]"))
    messageColor = noticeText;
else if (outputMessage.Contains("[Debug]"))
    messageColor = debugText;
else if (outputMessage.Contains("[Error]"))
    messageColor = errorText;
else if (outputMessage.Contains("[Note]"))
    messageColor = statusText;
else
    messageColor = normalText;
```

This works almost correctly. The issue happens when a output message contains multiple status like this for example:

```
[Info]: [SQL]: Connecting to the Log Database
```

I want it to only apply the colour for `[Info]` status, but it appears to be applying the colour of `[SQL]` status like this:

[image]

Is there a better way to do this? i.e. only detect the first occurrence of the status? or is my only option to juggle the if statements around to try and fit it in the order I want it to be detected?

This is my complete code snippet that's handling the log writing to custom output RTBs:

```
#region Process Output Handlers

void HandleServerOutput(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    // Ignore empty outputs
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
        return;

    // Workout target rich text box to write server output
    RichTextBox targetRTB = null;
    var processArg = (sender as Process).StartInfo.Arguments;
    if (processArg.Contains("run-mariadb.bat"))
    {
        targetRTB = dbLogsRTB;
    }
    else if (processArg.Contains("login-server.bat"))
    {
        targetRTB = loginLogsRTB;
    }
    else if (processArg.Contains("char-server.bat"))
    {
        targetRTB = charLogsRTB;
    }
    else if (processArg.Contains("map-server.bat"))
    {
        targetRTB = mapLogsRTB;
    }

    // Proceed if we know which target to write to
    if (null != targetRTB)
        WriteServerOutput(targetRTB, e.Data);
}

void WriteServerOutput(RichTextBox targetRTB, string outputMessage)
{
    this.UIThread(() =>
    {
        // Format message
        outputMessage = FormatOutput(outputMessage);

        // Workout message colour
        Color messageColor = normalText;
        if (outputMessage.Contains("[SQL]"))
            messageColor = sqlText;
        else if (outputMessage.Contains("[Status]"))
            messageColor = statusText;
        else if (outputMessage.Contains("[Warning]"))
            messageColor = warningText;
        else if (outputMessage.Contains("[Notice]"))
            messageColor = noticeText;
        else if (outputMessage.Contains("[Debug]"))
            messageColor = debugText;
        else if (outputMessage.Contains("[Error]"))
            messageColor = errorText;
        else if (outputMessage.Contains("[Note]"))
            messageColor = statusText;
        else
            messageColor = normalText;

        // Append message with colour
        RTBAppendText(targetRTB, messageColor, outputMessage);

        // Handle auto-scroll
        if (autoScrollLogs.Checked)
        {
            targetRTB.SelectionStart = targetRTB.Text.Length;
            targetRTB.ScrollToCaret();
        }
    });
}

void RTBAppendText(RichTextBox box, Color color, string text)
{
    int start = box.TextLength;
    box.AppendText(text);
    int end = box.TextLength;
    box.Select(start, end - start);
        box.SelectionColor = color;
    box.SelectionLength = 0;
}

string FormatOutput(string message)
{
    // Format server output
    return string.Format("[ {0} ] {1}",
        DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),
        message + Environment.NewLine);
}

#endregion
```

Comment: I would check outputMessage.indexOf(msgType) for each msgType and would selected minimum one that is >= 0

Comment: Is the timestamp part of the received string? Or are you adding that afterwards?

Comment: I am adding it afterwards. I'll update my question with complete code.

Comment: `[Info]` should use the normal text color?

Comment: Yea, as I noticed most of the output contains `[Info]` allot, so I use `normalText` colour, which is white.

Comment: You have a typo in the comment: "collour". ;) Also, don't forget to specify the access modifiers (`private`, `public`, etc.).

Comment: Isn't it private by default if you don't specify the access modifiers?

Comment: Yes, but it's a good practice to specify it. Different entities have different default visibility (classes, interfaces, etc.). Leaving empty those who match with the default only adds confusion. Code clarity is extremely important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the term nearest the start of the string you can't use `Contains` because it doesn't tell you where in the string the term is. To do that you're going to have to sort the position of each term in the string, and select the first term. You can do that in LINQ with:

```
var termHighlight = new Dictionary<string, Color>();
termHighlight.Add("SQL", sqlColor);
termHighlight.Add("Status", statusColor);
...

var keyIndexes = termHighlight.Select(t => new { Key = t.Key, Index = outputMessage.IndexOf('[' + t.Key + ']')}).Where(t => t.Index >= 0);
return keyIndexes.Any() ? termHighlight[keyIndexes.OrderBy(a => a.Index).First().Key] : Color.Black; // last is default color
```

Comment: Okay, this is definitely looking more like the solution I was after. Will try this tomorrow and report back. Thanks.

Comment: I honestly think this overcomplicates the logic and makes the code much harder to understand. He only needs a substring and a comparison. The `Dictionary` is a good idea though. Although it would be better to have it as a class property instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't simply find the substring you are interested in? For example:

```
this.UIThread(() =>
{
    // Workout message colour
    Color messageColor = normalText;

    int closingBracketIndex = outputMessage.IndexOf(']');
    if (closingBracketIndex > 2)
    {
        string msgType = outputMessage.Substring(1, closingBracketIndex - 1);

        switch (msgType)
        {
            case "SQL": messageColor = sqlText;
                break;
            case "Status": messageColor = statusText;
                break;
            case "Warning": messageColor = warningText;
                break;
            case "Notice": messageColor = noticeText;
                break;
            case "Debug": messageColor = debugText;
                break;
            case "Error": messageColor = errorText;
                break;
            case "Note": messageColor = statusText;
                break;
        }
    }

    // Format message
    outputMessage = FormatOutput(outputMessage);

    // Append message with colour
    RTBAppendText(targetRTB, messageColor, outputMessage);

    ...
}
```

But if you want the option that changes your code the least possible, you should change your `Contains` with `StartsWith` and move the `FormatOutput` line right before `RTBAppendText`.

**Option 2**

Inspired in Dour's answer, I'd like to add another option, which uses a `Dictionary`:

First, have this private property in your class:

```
private Dictionary<string, Color> typeColors;
```

Second, add this to your class' constructor:

```
typeColors = new Dictionary<string, Color>();
typeColors.Add("SQL", sqlText); // Just place here the color instead of using sqlText
typeColors.Add("Status", statusText); // Just place here the color instead of using statusText
...
typeColors.Add("Default", normalText); // Just place here the color instead of using normalText
```

Then, your code can be as simple (and readable) as this:

```
int closingBracketIndex = outputMessage.IndexOf(']');
string msgType = closingBracketIndex > 2 ? outputMessage.Substring(1, closingBracketIndex - 1) : string.Empty;
// Workout message colour
Color messageColor = typeColors.ContainsKey(msgType) ? typeColors[msgType] : typeColors["Default"];

// Format message
outputMessage = FormatOutput(outputMessage);

// Append message with colour
RTBAppendText(targetRTB, messageColor, outputMessage);
...
```

Comment: Question updated with full code snippet handling the process output.

Comment: I tried your regex idea, all output is normalText colour (white).

Comment: The regex was for the string with the timestamp, I removed it. It wouldn't make sense do this logic after adding that just to make things more complex. You should try my latest code.

Comment: Getting error: `Length cannot be less than zero. at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)`

Comment: Then one of the strings doesn't have a `]`. Can't you debug that?

Comment: I added a validation. Now if it can't find the brackets, it will use the default color.

Comment: Now, I am no longer getting any errors, but all the output are still back to being `normalText` (white) colour.

Comment: Aren't you able to debug the code to find out why that is happening? It still looks like `outputMessage` doesn't have the closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

You never delare the "[Info]" status.
When you put this as first "if", the "else" statements would not be hit.

```
// Workout message colour

Color messageColor;
If (outputMessage.Contains("[Info]"))
    messageColor=normalText;
if (outputMessage.Contains("[SQL]"))
    messageColor = sqlText;
else if (outputMessage.Contains("[Status]"))
    messageColor = statusText;
else if (outputMessage.Contains("[Warning]"))
    messageColor = warningText;
else if (outputMessage.Contains("[Notice]"))
    messageColor = noticeText;
else if (outputMessage.Contains("[Debug]"))
    messageColor = debugText;
else if (outputMessage.Contains("[Error]"))
    messageColor = errorText;
else if (outputMessage.Contains("[Note]"))
    messageColor = statusText;
else
    messageColor = normalText;
```

Comment: Your are missing an `else`. Anyway this won't work if the message has a `[Info]` in the middle.

Comment: Yes indeed. I typed this on my IPad while i coudn't sleep. Not the best time to answer questions.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like use a regex:

```
var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^\[ \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \] (\[\w+\])");
var match = regex.Match("[ 22:11:22 ] [Info]: [SQL] Blah");
if (string.Equals(match.Groups[1], "[Info]")) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a base class for every status and their especializations:

```
public abstract class Status
{
    public abstract Color Color { get; }

    public abstract string Pattern { get; }

    public int GetIndex(string lookup)
    {
        return lookup.IndexOf(Pattern);
    }
}

public class StatusSql : Status
{
    public override Color Color{ get; } = Color.Red;

    public override string Pattern { get; } = "[SQL]";
}

public class StatusInfo : Status
{
    public override Color Color { get; } = Color.White;

    public override string Pattern { get; } = "[INFO]";
}
```

You should also implement a class for every other status.

Then you could implement a method to check for the first occurence of that status:

```
    private static Color GetFirstStatusColor(string test)
    {
        List<Status> status = new List<Status>();

        status.Add(new StatusSql());
        status.Add(new StatusInfo());

        int currentMin = -1;
        bool foundOne = false;
        Status firstStatus = null;

        foreach(var stat in status)
        {
            int currStatusIndex = stat.GetIndex(test);

            if ((currStatusIndex < currentMin) || (!foundOne && currStatusIndex != -1))
            {
                firstStatus = stat;
                currentMin = currStatusIndex;
                foundOne = true;
            }
        }

        return firstStatus != null ? firstStatus.Color : Color.White;
    }
```

And then this code:

```
Color messageColor = normalText;
if (outputMessage.Contains("[SQL]"))
    messageColor = sqlText;
else if (outputMessage.Contains("[Status]"))
    messageColor = statusText;
else if (outputMessage.Contains("[Warning]"))
    messageColor = warningText;
else if (outputMessage.Contains("[Notice]"))
    messageColor = noticeText;
else if (outputMessage.Contains("[Debug]"))
    messageColor = debugText;
else if (outputMessage.Contains("[Error]"))
    messageColor = errorText;
else if (outputMessage.Contains("[Note]"))
    messageColor = statusText;
else
    messageColor = normalText;
```

Could become this:

```
Color messageColor = GetFirstStatusColor(outputMessage);
```

This way, if you ever want to change how you decide the color to display, it would be contained in a single place.

#### Edit

Instead of that static method, you could define a StatusList class with this responsability:

```
public class StatusList : List<Status>
{
    public Status GetFirstFoundStatus(string lookup)
    {
        int currentMin = -1;
        bool foundOne = false;
        Status firstStatus = null;

        foreach (var stat in this)
        {
            int currStatusIndex = stat.GetIndex(lookup);

            if ((currStatusIndex < currentMin) || (!foundOne && currStatusIndex != -1))
            {
                firstStatus = stat;
                currentMin = currStatusIndex;
                foundOne = true;
            }
        }

        return firstStatus;
    }
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
        StatusList statusList = new StatusList();

        statusList.Add(new StatusSql());
        statusList.Add(new StatusInfo());


        var status = statusList.GetFirstFoundStatus(test);

        return status != null ? status.Color : Color.White;
```

#### Edit 2

A slightly better approach would be to implement a factory instead of that list:

```
public class StatusFactory
{
    private List<Status> _possibleStatus;

    public StatusFactory()
    {
        _possibleStatus = new List<Status>();
        _possibleStatus.Add(new StatusInfo());
        _possibleStatus.Add(new StatusSql());
        _possibleStatus.Add(new StatusDefault());
    }

    public StatusFactory(IEnumerable<Status> possibleStatus)
    {
        _possibleStatus = new List<Status>();
        _possibleStatus.AddRange(possibleStatus);
    }

    public Status BuildMessageStatus(string message)
    {
        int currentIndex = -1;
        Status messageStatus = new StatusDefault();

        foreach(var status in _possibleStatus)
        {
            var statusIndex = status.GetIndex(message);

            if(statusIndex > -1 && ((currentIndex != -1 && statusIndex < currentIndex) || (currentIndex == -1)))
            {
                currentIndex = statusIndex;
                messageStatus = status;
            }
        }

        return messageStatus;
    }
}
```

Notice I have defined a DefaultStatus in case we can't find the correct Pattern in a string:

```
public class StatusDefault : Status
{
    public override Color Color { get; } = Color.White;

    protected override string Pattern { get; } = string.Empty;

    public override int GetIndex(string lookup)
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I have also made the GetIndex method virtual in the base class, and changed the access modifier of the Pattern property to protected.

The use of the current state of the code is:

```
StatusFactory factory = new StatusFactory();
Status status = factory.BuildMessageStatus(test);
Color messageColor = status.Color;
```

Comment: I like this OOP class approach. Will try it out later. Thanks. Just found that not all output contains a status. Does this code deals with this scenario ?

Comment: The last line of GetFirstStatusColor will default the return to White if it does not find any of the specified patterns.